# .Exe file not giving output through Task Scheduler C#

Tags: c#, outlook, windows-task-scheduler

I have an console application for sending mails on Outlook. When I try to run it's .exe by double clicking on it, it runs fine and emails are delivered but when I try to schedule it through Windows Task Scheduler it does not send any mail. In task scheduler it is showing task completed successfully but doesn't send any mail.
I tried various solution suggested on same type of questions but no luck. Please if can anyone suggest anything.

```
 Application app = new Application();
        MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = "Test mail";
        mailItem.To = "xxx@microsoft.com";
        mailItem.Body = "Test body";
        mailItem.Send();
        Console.WriteLine("mail send.....");
```

Comment: Which user are you running the task as? Is a user logged on when the task is scheduled to run? Do you have the 'Interact with Desktop' option ticked? You'll probably have to tell us which Library/COM component/etc you are using to send the mail?

Comment: @Milney have selected "Run whether user is logged on or not" and "Run with privileges". And user account is the default system account.

Comment: Well depending on how you are sending the mail that will not work, if you are using Outlook interop library, SYSTEM account probably doesn't have outlook profile, and if not logged on it won't have outlook COM started. Try using plain SMTP instead of Outlook connector. We can't help anymore unless you share the code you are using

Comment: @Milney Have updated the code

Comment: The Office's COM Automation library **is not intended to be used in headless scenarios** such as Windows' Task Scheduler (without an active user desktop environment to run in) and issues where things _won't work_ should be expected. You should read this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Comment: Also - Using COM Automation to send e-mail messages using Desktop Outlook is just **wrong** for so many reasons. Why aren't you using a proper SMTP client solution?

Comment: @Dai I tried SMTP code but it was giving me this error :  "*The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [PN1PR01CA0115.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"*.  So I opted for COM.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

You may consider as a possible workaround:

1. Use Exchange web services, see [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.
2. A low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. Or just any third-party libraries around API such as Redemption.